# ./ and bash doesn't work now, getting NO such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Found another problem, similar to my last question.

Tried to run this script from Brother's web site to install their print driver: (It's here: `[https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2300d_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625][1]`

(Now I renamed the actual file name with brp-install instead of typing that huge long file name.)

```
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ ls -lah br*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 kcredden kcredden 140K Apr  4 16:55 brp-install
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$
```

I tried:

```
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ sudo ./brp-install
[sudo] password for kcredden: 
-bash: ./brp-install: No such file or directory
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ 

kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ sudo bash brp-install
bash: brp-install: No such file or directory
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ 

kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ sudo bash brp-install
bash: brp-install: No such file or directory
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$
```

renamed the file with the .sh and tried again.

```
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ sudo bash brp-install.sh
bash: brp-install.sh: No such file or directory
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ sudo ./brp-install.sh
-bash: ./brp-install.sh: No such file or directory
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$ sudo /brp-install.sh
-bash: /brp-install.sh: No such file or directory
kcredden@zeus:/home/work/inbox$
```

What gives? I use to be able to run scripts with just bash, or ./ now I'm getting this.

The script actual is here:

```
    NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the gz file and not the aspx which is just the webpage that contains the download.

```
wget 'https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-2.gz'
```

unzip the file and make it executable:

```
gunzip *.gz
chmod +x linux-brprinter-installer*
```

run the file:

```
sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-2
```

The only other answer would be that you are running on ARM or something that is not amd64 or i386 which is required.